# Visual Studio 2017 Winforms: Load picture from project folder into Picture Box

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I would like to create several folders in the project folder where I can save my images. Then I would like to load these pictures into a PictureBox.

How can I now load the Info_Hydraulik.png image?

[An image with the path of the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QsWM.png)

Kind regards and thank you in advance for your help.

Flammel

Comment: `pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(this.GetType(), "Bu.Hell.Info_Hydraulik.png")`. If the Bitmap is an Embedded Resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `Info_Hydraulik.png` in Visual Studio's Properties change `Build Actions` to `Embedded Resource`.

If you use **WinForms** to load `PNG` to the `PictureBox':

```
using System.Reflection;

Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
// To list all resources use this:
// string[] names = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();
using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream
    ("WindowsFormsApp1.Bu.Hell.Info_Hydraulik.png"))
{
    Image image = Image.FromStream(stream);
    pictureBox1.Image = image;
}
```

Adjust the namespace `WindowsFormsApp1` in sample code to your project namespace.

Comment: I had to add `using System.IO;` and it worked. 
Thank you for your reponse